# xampp MySQL app not running (win8)

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I am using xampp for few month. But facing and error for 2 days and MySQL app isn't running. I reinstalled xampp and it was working fine, but when I restarted, it stopped working again. Here are error codes:

```
8:30:10 AM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
8:30:10 AM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 8 Pro  32-bit
8:30:10 AM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
8:30:10 AM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
8:30:10 AM  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
8:30:10 AM  [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
8:30:10 AM  [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
8:30:10 AM  [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
8:30:10 AM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
8:30:10 AM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
8:30:12 AM  [main]  All prerequisites found
8:30:12 AM  [main]  Initializing Modules
8:30:12 AM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
8:30:12 AM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
8:30:17 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
8:30:17 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
8:30:25 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
8:30:25 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
10:29:36 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to stop MySQL (PID: 5564)
10:29:36 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
10:29:36 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 5060)
10:29:36 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 5264)
10:29:37 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
10:29:39 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:29:44 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
10:29:45 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
10:29:55 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:30:56 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
```

Comment: `You are not running with administrator rights!` Did you tried ''Run as Administrator. Check event viewer for further error messages.

Comment: Hi @RenjuChandranchingath Thanks for your reply. I tried but no luck. So, I installed Wamp that is working fine now. Thanks